# Como somar 3 colunas de tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, mysql, sql-select

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema financeiro. Hoje temos a seguinte situação:

- Bancos (id, nome, saldoInicial);
- Receitas (id, geraParcela, qtdeParcelas)
- Receitas_parcelas (id, id_receita, valor, data_vencimento)
- Despesas (id, geraParcela, qtdeParcelas)
- Despesas_parcelas (id, id_despesa, valor, data_vencimento)

Fiz um `SELECT` no *MySQL* para somar a coluna `saldoInicial` + `valor(receita)` - `valor(despesa)`.

O select ficou da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT SUM(rp.par_valor) + SUM(b.ban_saldoInicial) - SUM(dp.des_valor) AS total FROM bancos b  
INNER JOIN receitas r ON (b.id_banco = r.id_banco)
INNER JOIN receitas_parcelas rp ON (r.id_receita = rp.id_receita)
INNER JOIN despesas d ON (b.id_banco = d.id_banco) 
INNER JOIN despesas_parcelas dp ON (d.id_despesa = dp.id_despesa) 
WHERE id_banco = ID AND rp.par_status = 1 AND dp.par_status = 1
```

No SELECT acima, deveria somar todos os valores das parcelas das receitas que tiverem recebidas, todas as parcelas das despesas que estiverem pagas e o saldo inicial do banco.

Só que, se por exemplo, não houver nenhum registro em receitas ou em despesas, o resultado volta `NULL`.

Existe alguma outra forma de somar do jeito que preciso só com *MySQL*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que a seguinte *query*, usando *subqueries*, funciona:

```
SELECT b.ban_saldoInicial + (
    SELECT sum(rp.valor)
    FROM receitas r
    INNER JOIN receitas_parcelas rp ON rp.id_receita = r.id_receita
    WHERE r.id_banco = ID
    AND rp.par_status = 1) - (
    SELECT SUM(dp.valor)
    FROM despesas d
    INNER JOIN despesas_parcelas dp ON dp.id_despesa = d.id_despesa
    WHERE d.id_banco = ID
    AND dp.par_status = 1)
FROM bancos b
WHERE id_banco = ID;
```

Comment: Me atendeu perfeitamente, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function [coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
SELECT SUM(coalesce(rp.par_valor,0)) + ...
```